# Copying a file only when it is newer than the destination

Tags: linux, cp

How do I copy a file in Linux only when the file being copied is newer than the version at the destination?

If the file at the destination  is newer, I want the file copy to not go ahead.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Using the update option (-u) with cp should do it for you.

http://beginnerlinuxtutorial.com/help-tutorial/basic-linux-commands/cp-linux-copy-command/

Comment: To save future readers some time: this question is tagged Linux. Non-GNU cp implementations (BSD, macOS, etc.) lack the `-u` option. You can use `rsync --update` instead.

Comment: On FreeBSD you may want to install `coreutils` package with `pkg install coreutils`. Then, among others, you will have GNU cp under the name `gcp`. Note that there is also brew package `coreutils` which also provide `gcp`.

Answer (score 32):

Use [rsync](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/rsync)

```
rsync --progress -r -u /from/one/* /to/another/directory
```

Comment: Just for completeness: `-r` means recursive operation into subdirectories and `-u` to keep newer files at destination (=update). `--progress` shows progress information during operation.

Comment: I strongly suggest to add the `-t` option in order to keep the timestamp from the source

Comment: i suggest also add -p to keep the same chmod and chown
 rsync --progress -rutp

Answer (score 9):

You're not saying what shell you're using, so I'm going to assume `ksh`:

```
if [[ file1 -nt file2 ]]; then cp file1 file2; fi
```

Comment: Isn't bash most common?

Comment: @Rob, yes. This works in bash too, obviously. I just didn't have bash (or any standard Linux box) at hand when I wrote it.

Answer (score 5):

`yes|cp -ruv /from/* /to/.`
yes - Answer yes to all the questions.
r - Recursive
u - update
v - Progress

works like *xargs*.

I don't know how to explain academically.

[How to force cp to overwrite without confirmation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8488292/879613)

Comment: This is kind of cryptic.  Can you expand your answer to be a little more explicit, maybe include an example?  Thanks.  [from Review](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/592062)

Comment: yes -> Answer yes to all the questions.

Comment: TIL: `cp` has a progress flag!